# jQuery Lightbox or equivalent with image array

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm trying to implement a [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)-style gallery where clicking a text link launches a slideshow of images that are loaded from an array, not from inline content on the page. All the examples I can find use a group of inline images that are related somehow (i.e. using a rel tag or class). I want to define my images using their paths in a Javascript array.

Anyone know the solution or have any pointers? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works with the example you can download from the plugin site.

Demo [here](http://redsquare.gogo2.co.cc/lb/)

```
$(function() {
        $('#testLink').click( dynamicLightBoxinit );
    });

    function dynamicLightBoxinit(){
        images = ["photos/image1.jpg", "photos/image2.jpg","photos/image3.jpg","photos/image4.jpg","photos/image5.jpg"];
        var imageBuilder='';
        for (var i = 0; i  < images.length; i++)  {

            imageBuilder += '<a href="'+images[i]+'"><img src="';
            imageBuilder += images[i];
            imageBuilder += '" \></a>';
          }

          var lb = $(imageBuilder);
          lb.lightBox();
          lb.filter('a:first').click();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks redsquare, your solution works perfectly and is precisely what I was looking for. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but is this something you're looking for?

```
images = ["path1.jpg", "path2.jpg"];
for (var i = 0; i  < images.length; i++)
  {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = images[i];
    images[i] = img;
  }
```

Rather blunt in-place replacement of the urls to Image-objects, but it was shorter to write.

Your images will be loaded by the browser when the src-attribute is set, and can be appended to any html container per normal dom-operations.

HTH.